# Create a Json Object Name With Dynamic String Variable

Tags: javascript

I want to code an object name with a dynamic string variable.

```
this.datas: [ 
{
    name: "john",
    data: 10
}
{
    name: "add",
    data: 20
}
]

this.latestBarChart: {
    chartName: "Line",
    style: "red"
}


for (let i = 0; i < this.datas.length; i++) {
        this.screenData[i].data.push(JSON.parse(`${this.datas[i].name}`: this.latestBarChart)); 
}
```

I tried like this. But there is an error because of this `:` while I push

```
this.screenData[i].data.push(JSON.parse(`${this.datas[i].name}`: this.latestBarChart));
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Why do you use `JSON.parse`? There is no JSON there. And what is your expected result? Did you check the documentation of `push`?

Comment: if I do not use `JSON.parse`, there is still same error

Comment: there's no such thing as a JSON object - JSON is a string notation of an object, but not an object

Comment: Yes, but you should not just try and try. First make clear what you want to do and then think how you will do it.

Comment: .push({}), you forgot the curly brackets

Comment: @AlexB I tried same thing, but there is same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ES6 you can use the computed key syntax like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.datas.length; i++) {
  this.screenData[i].data.push({ [this.datas[i].name]: this.latestBarChart })
}
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to do this:

```
this.screenData[i].data.push({ [this.datas[i].name]: this.latestBarChart });
```

Note that there is no JSON in your code, so there is no reason to use `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 2):

```
I think you want to do this. 

for (let i = 0; i < this.datas.length; i++) {
        this.screenData[i].data.push({
          [this.datas[i].name]: this.latestBarChart
        }); 
}

This will create array with objects inside screenData.data. Objects would look like this.
{
  john: {
    chartName: "Line",
    style: "red"
  },
  ...
}
```